# is there a way to *getRotationAngleAtLength(in float distance)* similar to getPointAtLength(in float distance)

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, smil

Hey folks and fellow geeks!

I have this revolutionary idea for Web 3.0, hehe.
I'm gonna create a SVG-UI-lib a la jQuery-UI.
In order to make some features possible I need to fork/contribute to d3.js.
ie. I want to be able to animate/position along curves/paths.

Yes, I know there is Raphael, but then d3 is on github and I prefer d3s' syntax ...

So, what I'm thinking about right now is how to create scrollbars that actually are not straight lines but paths - very "flashy", huh?

So, I found one way to do this using SMIL:
Using some combination of beginElementAt() and endElementAt() or pausAnimations() would allow me to animate along a path ... with no time to exactly that position by utilizing the paths.<strike>pathLength attr</strike> .getTotalLength() method --- using the rotation attribute I can even let it be rotated along the paths inclination

So in a different post here I found out about the wonderful method getPointAtLength(0..1)
This would make it like easy to create a scrollbar along a path ...
And I don't really need the rotation as it's not a bad thing if the handle is always orientated in a 90 deg manner so as to hint to it's driving direction.

But anyway, I would like to know,

**_ IS THERE A METHOD LIKE THIS getPointAtLength(0..1) THAT REPRESENTS ORIENTATION ??? _**

Cheers, Joehannes

Comment: If I understand `getPointAtLength` correctly, it should be a trivial matter to calculate the angle between two such points.

Comment: @Shmiddty the path can be a bezier curve so the angle is not contant.

Comment: @Duopixel If you are looking for the "orientation" of a point at some place along the path, you can approximate it by simply grabbing a point before it and a point after it, and calculating the angle between them. Obviously, you'd want to make the distance between these points as small as possible.

Comment: @Joehannes there is no native way to do this. Look ath the implementation

Comment: @Duopixel thx, I think you are right, but I think I found a way to do this that's again involving SMIL, but more directly ... --> see my answer

Comment: @Shmiddty I'm afraid Duopixel seems to be right, it's not that easy. As it is a curve and only it's control points are known (the bending part of the curve is painted by an algorithm of the host/browser) you cannot pick those other points you'd need to interpolate, or rather you have no way of knowing the angle/orientation of those points (yes, you can pick them with the very same getPointAtLength(+-0.01)...) --- therefore, *my* math cannot solve this ... I did some at uni, but I really think it's not possible without the underlying algorithm the browser uses to paint the curve

Comment: `Math.atan2(y2-y1,x2-x1)` Will give you the angle between any two points.

Comment: If you want to set up an example in jsFiddle, I might be able to produce the code for you (and I'm interested in trying).

Comment: @Shmiddty ... actually, that sounds surprisingly promising! but hold on. OK, let's do this, am gonna set up a fiddle and post it, but as the lib I want to write doesn't exist yet, I gotta take some time, gimme an hour.

Comment: @Shmiddty : hm, just theorizing. How would you approach this? say you have a point at x: 1, y: 1 ... you'd take two other points, one slightly after, one slightly before and do your atan2-magic on it. that would give you *the* angle. Only thing that irks me with this is, you'd have to make always make sure there are no curve-twisting control-points in between your chosen, angle-deriving, coordinate-tuples. How to do that? Any idea? Of course you can always make the distance ridiculously small, but then it's always prone to error in extreme cases ...

Comment: @Joehannes worst case scenario, it's the average inclination. I'm not sure it's terribly important to be 100% accurate.

Comment: @Shmiddty I can't seem to get the fiddle working --- http://jsfiddle.net/joehannes/UT69H/13/ --- the problem is the pathLength attr isn't working. it is a "SVGAnimatedNumberObject" ... but it's baseVal is 0 ... at least in Chrome ... ideas? ahm, before this commentlist gets banned/deleted/sth, I suggest we start mailing or something if you want to give it a go ... for a start, I'll be on freenode in svg-ui-d3 for a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gotten it working pretty roughly: http://jsfiddle.net/UT69H/18/

It's really jittery, but it rotates with the path. Note that I moved the mousemove handler to the body element so that it doesn't abruptly stop if your mouse moves outside of the box itself.

```
bod.on "mousemove", () ->
    if mousedown
         pos = getPosHandle { x: d3.mouse(h[0][0])[0], y: d3.mouse(h[0][0])[1] }  
         pos1 = getPosHandle { x: d3.mouse(h[0][0])[0], y: d3.mouse(h[0][0])[1] - 1 } 
         pos2 = getPosHandle { x: d3.mouse(h[0][0])[0], y: d3.mouse(h[0][0])[1] + 1 }
         ang = Math.round(Math.atan2(pos2.y - pos1.y, pos2.x - pos1.x) * 180 / Math.PI) - 90
         h.attr "transform", "rotate(#{ang} #{pos.x} #{pos.y})"
         h.attr "x", (pos.x - h.attr("width") / 2)
         h.attr "y", (pos.y - h.attr("height") / 2)
```

This is a bit better: http://jsfiddle.net/UT69H/19/

```
bod.on "mousemove", () ->
    if mousedown
         pos = getPosHandle { x: d3.mouse(bod[0][0])[0], y: d3.mouse(bod[0][0])[1] }  
         pos1 = getPosHandle { x: d3.mouse(bod[0][0])[0], y: d3.mouse(bod[0][0])[1] - 1 } 
         pos2 = getPosHandle { x: d3.mouse(bod[0][0])[0], y: d3.mouse(bod[0][0])[1] + 1 }
         ang = Math.round(Math.atan2(pos2.y - pos1.y, pos2.x - pos1.x) * 180 / Math.PI) - 90
         h.attr "transform", "rotate(#{ang} #{pos.x} #{pos.y})"
         h.attr "x", (pos.x - h.attr("width") / 2)
         h.attr "y", (pos.y - h.attr("height") / 2)
```

You can reduce the jitter by spacing the test points further out: http://jsfiddle.net/UT69H/21/

```
bod.on "mousemove", () ->
    if mousedown
         pos = getPosHandle { x: d3.mouse(bod[0][0])[0], y: d3.mouse(bod[0][0])[1] }  
         pos1 = getPosHandle { x: d3.mouse(bod[0][0])[0], y: d3.mouse(bod[0][0])[1] - 4 } 
         pos2 = getPosHandle { x: d3.mouse(bod[0][0])[0], y: d3.mouse(bod[0][0])[1] + 4 }
         ang = Math.round(Math.atan2(pos2.y - pos1.y, pos2.x - pos1.x) * 180 / Math.PI) - 90
         h.attr "transform", "rotate(#{ang} #{pos.x} #{pos.y})"
         h.attr "x", (pos.x - h.attr("width") / 2)
         h.attr "y", (pos.y - h.attr("height") / 2)
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UT69H/20/ This will work for almost any path, though perhaps a bit quirkily.

Comment: hey, that's pretty cool. I like the way you interpolate the euclidian distance when it comes to a path that's not only following one axis, but two dimensions :) I just wondered how you could get rid of the quirkyness ... you'd have to calculate the angle and see if it's above or below 45°, get rid of the euclidian formula and just do a switch of if so, use this axis as formula-base, if different the other ... possible I guess, cool man, keep it up

Comment: @Joehannes Pretty good idea. The syntax of coffeescript throws me a bit, so I didn't play around too much, but I'm sure you can take it from here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my question actually is/was if there is a rather programmatic/javascript way of doing this, not involving SMIL or at least not involving the animate-functionality.
It seems a bit hacky to misuse an animate-tag just to set a value ...

Well, I found out about another tag which is again SMIL, so not pure js, but it looks rather like something that's rather intended for this purpose:

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#SetElement ... will you enable to use all the attrs/params of the "normal" animation-tags, but doesn't involve - at least I guess so by its name - animating in the first place and stopping immediately. It will enable me to just say begin="onBegin" and then invoke the beginElement() method.

**EDIT**:
OK, set is not that cool. it is not able to use the animateMotion-specific-props which I would need to animate along a path